# reload minor mode after every change within emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

How to reload the definition of minor mode so that it can be loaded after every change to it within emacs. This will greatly improve the workflow of developing minor mode.

For example, In the following minor mode there is an error in the anonymous function, Using the key C-x X-e to reload the definition of minor mode and then disabling and enabling the minor mode in a buffer does not use the new definition.

```
(define-minor-mode bb-sample-mode
  "Minor mode for sample projects"
  :init-value nil
  :lighter "bb-sample"
  :keymap
  '(([f1] . '(lambda()
          (interactive)
          (message "laksdjflskj")))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy:

```
(define-key bb-sample-mode-map [f1]
  (lambda() (interactive) (message "foo")))
```

You don't even have to disable/enable. This will just work.

### UPD

OK, with this it should surely work:

```
(defvar bb-sample-mode-map (make-sparse-keymap))

(define-minor-mode bb-sample-mode
  "Minor mode for sample projects"
  :init-value nil
  :lighter "bb-sample"
  :keymap bb-sample-mode-map)
```

Comment: Throws error Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable bb-sample-mode-map)
  (define-key bb-sample-mode-map [f1] (lambda nil (interactive) (message "foo")))
  eval((define-key bb-sample-mode-map [f1] (lambda nil (interactive) (message "foo"))) nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)

Comment: `bb-sample-mode-map` becomes defined when you define the minor mode.

Comment: I did that first (key "C-x C-e"). Still the error is same. The define-minor-mode looks like this :----  
(define-minor-mode bb-sample-mode
  "Minor mode for sample projects"
  :init-value nil
  :lighter "bb-sample")

Comment: It will work if you use the minor mode definition from the question.

Comment: It did not work. Seems F1 is grabbed by the global help. The message gets displayed "f1 (Type ? for further options)-"

Comment: Did you activete to minor mode?

Comment: Thank you very much(Sherlock :) ). That was precise guess(?). It works. By the way is the defvar required. Can't this be written as (define-minor-mode bb-sample-mode
  "Minor mode for sample projects"
  :init-value nil
  :lighter "bb-sample"
  :keymap (make-sparse-keymap))

Answer (score 2):

Better not use the `:keymap` argument in general, and in this case it would indeed help you:

```
(defvar bb-sample-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [f1] (lambda () ...))
    map))

(define-minor-mode bb-sample-mode
  "Minor mode for sample projects."
  :lighter "bb-sample")
```

Then `C-M-x` will redefine the keymap when you're inside the first expression (because `C-M-x` handles `defvar' specially).
You might also like to give a name to your command:

```
(defun bb-sample-foo ()
  (interactive)
  (message "laksdjflskj"))

(defvar bb-sample-mode-map
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
    (define-key map [f1] 'bb-sample-foo)
    map))
```

so you can `C-M-x` from within the function, which will take effect immediately.

Comment: Throws error Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-number-of-arguments define-key 2)
  (define-key [f1] (lambda nil (message "yyyy")))
  (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap))) (define-key [f1] (lambda nil (message "yyyy"))) map)
  (defvar bb-sample-mode-map (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap))) (define-key [f1] (lambda nil (message "yyyy"))) map))
  eval((defvar bb-sample-mode-map (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap))) (define-key [f1] (lambda nil (message "yyyy"))) map)) nil)
  eval-last-sexp-1(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)

Comment: That's because I forgot an argument.  Fixed.